# Nested vectors in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, templates, vector, g++

I'm trying to implement a DivideAndConquer template. The original project was in VisualStudio 2013, but when I move the source code to Linux I get errors.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename Element>
class DivideAndConquer
{
    public:
        ~DivideAndConquer(){}
        vector<Element> solve(vector<Element> p);

    protected:
        virtual bool isSimple(vector<Element> p) = 0;
        virtual vector<Element> simplySolve(vector<Element> p) = 0;
        virtual vector<vector<Element>> decompose(vector<Element> p) = 0;
        virtual vector<Element> combine(vector<vector<Element>> p) = 0;
};
```

The error reads `DivideAndConquer.h:28: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression`. I have comments in my version, so line 28 is the declaration of the decompose function. There are similar errors for all declarations involving nested vectors across all other .h files.

Does Linux allow nested vectors in this fasion? I really don't want to keep track of an array's size throughout my whole implementation.

Comment: Separate the two `>` by a space character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blaming linux for your minor mistake...

```
    virtual vector<vector<Element>> decompose(vector<Element> p) = 0;
```

This should be :-

```
    virtual vector<vector<Element> > decompose(vector<Element> p) = 0;

>> should be separated > >
```

Comment: Or use `-std=gnu++0x`, `-std=gnu++11`, or later

Comment: Let me guess, it's because >> is the cin operator right?

Comment: The parser using "maximal munch" tokenizes the >> as an operator before the template brackets.

Comment: It's because `>>` **was** the right-shift operator in C++98. Under the current C++ rules, `>>` inside nested template argument lists closes two of them.